# Backspace Ascii value vs integer?

Tags: java, ascii

So far I have a text field that accepts only numbers, backspace, delete, decimal and hyphens. The block of code with is:

```
if ( ((keyChar > '0') && (keyChar < '9')) ||
(keyChar == '.') || (keyChar == '-') ||
(keyChar == 8 )  || (keyChar == 127) )
```

This works however when I leave out the "(keyChar == 8 )  ||" and use

```
if ( ((keyChar > '0') && (keyChar < '9')) ||
(keyChar == '.') || (keyChar == '-') ||
(keyChar == 127) )
```

The backspace key does not work even though it is between 0 and 9?

Comment: between 0 and 9, not '0' and '9', cus '0' is somewhere 48

Comment: 8 and '8' are very different things.

Comment: keyChar > '0' equals to keyChar > 48, keyChar < '9' equals to keyChar < 57, each character denotes to appropriate number in coding page. Backspace has no writable sign, but it's number code is 8, not '8'

Answer (score 2):

> The backspace key does not work even though it is between 0 and 9?

The backspace key does not generate a character, its value is undefined. A character is something that can actually be displayed in a text component.

Assuming this is Swing then don't attempt to solve this by using a KeyListener. Swing has newer and better API's:

1. See [Using a Formatted Text Field](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) for a component will built in support for this
2. See [Implementing a DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) for implementing you own custom editing of valid characters.